# Mapping of a struct returns empty fields

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, hardhat

I'm following [this thread](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82413/explicit-declaration-the-var-keyword-is-not-allowed-syntax-error/82415) to store iterable data in a mapping by referencing a struct. (code sample [here](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#8tuol8mpj0vx9ufgo48yc)) However when trying to return information I simply get empty values (I'm sending correct data through a JS test script):

[image: console screenshot]

The retrieval function is just like this one:

```
function getInstructor(address _address) view public returns (uint, string memory, string memory) {
    return (instructors[_address].age, instructors[_address].fName, instructors[_address].lName);
}
```

**Needless to say, I'm using Solidity 0.8.0.**

I'd appreciate a lot your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have many code issues that rendered you code uncompilable. Looks were using a lot of non-Solidity syntax. I had to perform the following edits to make your code compile:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Courses {

    struct Instructor {
        uint age;
        string fName;
        string lName;
    }

    mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;
    address[] public instructorAccts;

    function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string memory _fName, string memory _lName) public {
        Instructor memory instructor = instructors[_address];

        instructor.age = _age;
        instructor.fName = _fName;
        instructor.lName = _lName;

        instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
    }

    function getInstructors() view public returns (address[] memory) {
        return instructorAccts;
    }

    function getInstructor(address _address) view public returns (uint, string memory, string memory) {
        return (instructors[_address].age, instructors[_address].fName, instructors[_address].lName);
    }

    function countInstructors() view public returns (uint) {
        return instructorAccts.length;
    }

}
```

After making these edits, it is clear where the issue lies. Observe the following line:

```
Instructor memory instructor = instructors[_address];
```

The line defines the instructor in memory, which means any modifications to it would simply disappear after function execution is over. There is no object aliasing here. When you copy a created struct from storage to memory, any changes done to the memory struct would not reflect to storage. You need to copy the memory-based instructor into storage after being done with the modifications by placing the following line near the end of the function declaration:

```
instructors[_address] = instructor;
```

Comment: Thanks! It's functional now. 
And I apologize for the issues on that sample, I should have checked it out before sharing.